# Selenium: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, geckodriver

I'm trying to get the text within the element `id='resultStats'` from the Google Search Result Page for the following query https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://theshipibomarket.com/

I get an output with the code I've got but it's not the text within the element. The output is:
`[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="5a1e4063-dcb8-48b2-93f6-1c60bb7e9e05", element="63dabd48-bd5f-4380-9598-173b91e72367")>]`

When I use the `.text` function on the `results` element I get the follow error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

Here's my code:

```
# import libraries
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
options = Options()
options.headless = True

query = "site:https://theshipibomarket.com/"
urlpage = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+query
print(urlpage)
# run firefox webdriver from executable path of your choice
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
# get web page
driver.get(urlpage)
# execute script to scroll down the page
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
# sleep for 30s
time.sleep(30)
# driver.quit()

# find elements by xpath
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='resultStats']")
#print('Number of results', len(results))
print("The number of pages Google have index {}".format(results.text))
```

I suspect that because it's javascript that this is causing the issue, as the output is a `list`. I've not got much experience scraping Google or doing a lot of scraping in general so apologise if this is a simple misunderstanding on my behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line to:

```py
print("The number of pages Google have index {}".format(results[0].text)) # added zero
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Works perfectly! Such a simple fix. :)